# PLSQL Getting expression is of wrong type

Tags: oracle, plsql, user-defined-types

I'm a newbee to PLSQL and I'm facing issues while created PLSQL function.It says expression is of wrong type.I need some help.
Here is my function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HOTGROUPTYPE AS OBJECT (
  IMEI           VARCHAR2(255),
  LACCI  VARCHAR2(255),
  FRAUD_TYPE VARCHAR2(255),
  MSISDN VARCHAR2(255)
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE HOTGROUPTYPE_tab IS TABLE OF HOTGROUPTYPE;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf (p_count IN NUMBER, p_days IN NUMBER) RETURN HOTGROUPTYPE_tab 
AS
l_tab  HOTGROUPTYPE_tab:=HOTGROUPTYPE_tab();
BEGIN
  for i in (select IMEI,LACCI,FRAUD_TYPE,MSISDN 
  from fms_fraud_master_tbl 
  where request_type='BARRING' 
  and rownum<2)
  loop
  l_tab.extend;
  l_tab(l_tab.last) := i.IMEI;
  end loop;

  RETURN l_tab;
END;
/
```

And I'm getting this error when the execute the function

```
11/3     PL/SQL: Statement ignored
11/28    PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not assigning the values to your table type properly. `l_tab(<index>)` must be assigned the variable of type `HOTGROUPTYPE`.

You must use this:

```
l_tab(l_tab.last) := HOTGROUPTYPE(i.IMEI, i.LACCI,i.FRAUD_TYPE,i.MSISDN );
```

Comment: @Tejesh Thank you so much...its working as expected

Answer (score 0):

The neatest way to populate a collection from a query is to use bulk collect:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_tab_tf (p_count IN NUMBER, p_days IN NUMBER) RETURN HOTGROUPTYPE_tab 
AS
  l_tab  HOTGROUPTYPE_tab:=HOTGROUPTYPE_tab();
BEGIN

  select HOTGROUPTYPE( IMEI,LACCI,FRAUD_TYPE,MSISDN )
  bulk collect into l_tab
  from fms_fraud_master_tbl 
  where request_type='BARRING' ;

  RETURN l_tab;

END;
/
```